# How to automate push notifications on Desktop?

Tags: selenium, push-notification, automated-tests

I want to automate push notifications on Desktop. i.e. I want to automate push notification when sent by Chrome and Firefox. I have search enough online but unable to get any concrete solutions/information.

Since the delivered push notification is not a part of browser and hence it cannot be detected by Selenium. Any other ways one can automate this?

Comment: The edit from May 8 had a reason given in the edit comment. But again:  It was a community decision to get rid of the [qa] tag. See [The \[qa\] tag has been burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/414992) for reference. Don't roll back such edits.

Answer (score 0):

What about UiAutomation? I'd look towards it. It could handle both Silverlight and win/wpf applications

Comment: Thanks. I checked about it but looks like this will not fulfil the purpose since I am using Mac OS and also the tool looks a bit complex to setup.